# svg and svgz doesn't display after adding remove the trailing slash in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, svg, svgz

Here is my .htaccess file

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /(.*[^/]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*              /%1         [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}      !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html  -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !\.html  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   %{REQUEST_URI}.html  [NC,L]
```

svg and svgz works fine if the web url format looks like `www.myweb.com/index.html` and or `www.myweb.com/index`

But if the url looks like this way,(a trailing slash at the end of the url) `www.myweb.com/index/` text contents are fine, but unable to see svg and svgz images! Must be the .htaccess is not quite right somewhere. If someone could help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a relative/absolute URL issue. If you're linking using relative links and you create an additional path node (the second `/`) which changes the relative URI base, and from that point, every relative URI will have `/index/` appended to the front. You need to either change all of those URLs to absolute (start with a `/`) or include a relative base in the page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```